# can admin submit for user when both login from same table

Tags: sql

```
tblUser(userid,fullname,emailid,password)
```

admin and user login through this table

```
tblPersonalInfo(pinfoid,firstname,lastname,userid)
```

personal information enter there by user through userid

```
tblAcdemic(asid,metricmarks,fscmarks,userid)
```

Here I want to insert academic record by adminfor user, so I am confuse to use pinfoid as fk in tblAcdemic table, so what i do in this Senereio. also i need help for writing stored procedure for tblAcdemic in sql server.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?  The question isn't very clear.  It looks like `tblAcademic` has a FK to `tblUser`, so if you want to insert a record into `tblAcademic` for a specific user then you just need to specify that user's `userid` in the record, right?

Comment: the issue is that, user ABC is registered and i as an admin want to enter the academic record in tblAcademic for ABC, now suggest me that can i use pinfoid for ABC user?

Comment: and more clear can i add pinfoid to tblAcdemic for ABC user??

Comment: @David sir can you got my point?

Comment: No, your point is not clear at all.  If you're inserting a record into `tblAcademic` then what does `pinfoid` have to do with it?  And what does the admin user have to do with whether or not you can insert records into the database?  If you have the identifier for the user record you're editing, you can use that identifier in any `WHERE` clause you need in the database.  I see no reason why an admin wouldn't be able to edit another user's data.  Indeed, that's often _supposed_ to be what an admin user does.

Comment: @David thanks. Today i got the answer of my own question. i have two user for tblUser. one is admin by self and other is any user suppose `ABC`. `ABC` just enter his peronal info and not a permission to insert the academic record. Now the `admin` will insert the acdamic record for `ABC` as admin login by same `tblUser` table.Actually i was confused that how admin will determine that for which `ABC` user the admin entering the data. So the admin will retrive  `userid` as `FK` in `tblPersonalInfo` table to enter the data in `tblAcademic` table.